# how to fix the end of procedure trigger error

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

is there a way to fix this error or there is something i am missing in my code,im learning `postgresql` and i have been working on `table inheritance and triggers` i have two tables the `temporary_object table` and the `persons table` the persons table inherits all the properties the the temporary object has,then i have created a trigger function on the persons table which checks the records with the same `id before updating` the `tables` my problem comes when i try to run the `insert query`,im getting these `errors`

```
ERROR: end of trigger procedure achieved without RETURN
CONTEXT: function PL / pgSQL muli_function ()

ERROR: end of trigger procedure achieved without RETURN
SQL-state: 2F005
Context: The PL / pgSQL muli_function ()
```

this is by insert query

```
INSERT INTO persons (id, time_create, time_dead, First_name, Last_name) values (1, '2011-10-07 15:25:00 EDT', '2011-10-07 3:25 PM EDT', 'sathiya', 'james');
```

and this my trigger function and trigger itself

```
CREATE FUNCTION muli_function() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
     UPDATE persons
     SET time_dead = NEW.time_create
     Where
         id = NEW.id
         AND time_dead IS NULL
         ;
  RETURN new;
  END IF;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER sofgr BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
        ON persons FOR each ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE muli_function();
```

and these are my two tables query

```
CREATE TABLE temporary_object
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  time_create timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  time_dead timestamp without time zone,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, time_create)
);

CREATE TABLE persons
(

  First_Name text,
  Last_Name text
)
INHERITS (temporary_object);
```

Comment: Why is `muli_function` bound to INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE when it only cares about UPDATE? And you might want to learn about dollar quoting, very handy for functions.

Comment: Thre is no need to use an UPDATE statement for the table on which the trigger has fired. Just assign the value using `new.time_dead := new.time_create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION muli_function() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
     UPDATE persons
     SET time_dead = NEW.time_create
     Where
         id = NEW.id
         AND time_dead IS NULL
         ;

  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

UPD Better something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION muli_function() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = ''UPDATE'' THEN
    IF NEW.time_dead IS NULL THEN
     NEW.time_dead = NEW.time_create
    END IF;      
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The latter query does a completely different thing: it changes `time_dead` in the _current_ row, not in the others as the first one.

Comment: @dezso I assumed, that `id` field is a PK. Equal PK -> same record.

Comment: At first glance I assumed the same, but the OP says: 'which checks the records with the same id before updating'

Answer (score 1):

You define the trigger procedure for an `INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger, but don't provide a case for the `INSERT` (just as mu is too short is commented), only the `UPDATE`.  So the trigger executes the procedure for an `INSERT`, then it does not find anything to execute and exits without a `RETURN`, which is obviously an error.